# Scala syntax for iteration? Or something else?

Tags: scala

I saw some code like this. 
From REPL test, it looks like "/:" iterates through chars and call incr repeatedly. But I can't find any document for this syntax.
What does /: syntax mean here?

```
val chars = List('a','b')
def incr(acc:Map[Char, Int], c:Char) = {
   val count = (acc get c).getOrElse(0) + 1
    acc + ((c, count))
}

(Map[Char,Int]() /: chars)(incr)
```

Comment: check the scaladoc for Map ;) http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map@/:[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=>B):B

Comment: Looks like it is foldLeft right?

Comment: It's just a method call like any other method call. It's *not* special syntax. Very few things in Scala are, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce.scala#L1):

```
   *  Note: `/:` is alternate syntax for `foldLeft`; `z /: xs` is the same as
   *  `xs foldLeft z`
```